# Unexpected token '*' and '-' in R

Tags: r

Can you please tell me if you see something wrong with my code:

```
GMVPort=timeSeries(cumprod(GMVRetFac),charvec = names (GMVRetFac) )

CVARPort=timeSeries(cumprod(CVARRetFac),charvec = names (CVARRetFac))

## Plotting of portfolio values

ylims=range(cbind(GMVPort, CVARPort))

plot (GMVPort,  ylim = ylims ,  xlab = "",ylab = "Portfolio Value (Index)")

lines (CVARPort,  col = "blue")

legend(" topleft ",legend = c ( "Minimum−Variance","Minimum−CVaR" ),col = c("black" , "blue") ,  lty = 1)

## Relative performance

RelOutPerf=((CVARPort−GMVPort)/GMVPort)∗100
```

i face a message saying Unexpected token for the - and * for the last line

Any idea ?

Thank you

Comment: If I define CVARPort and GMVPort as numeric variables it works for me.

Comment: @Dason touches on a good point--this example isn't really reproducible and so it's hard for us to debug.  Could you edit your question to tell us how CARPort and GMVPort are defined?

Comment: Are you sure that you can do mathematical operations on `timeSeries` objects? I assume you're using the `timeSeries` package here (you really should specify what packages you're using)? I don't think `timeSeries` objects can be manipulated like they were `numeric` objects.

Comment: I'm not used to manipulate these object, but it's a copy and paste from https://englianhu.files.wordpress.com/2017/09/financial-risk-modelling-and-portfolio-optimization-with-r-2nd-edt.pdf page 253 line 26

Comment: hi pierre if this question is related to the second one you just posted you might mark it as duplicate or remove it :-)